# como valido radioButtons en kotlin

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

estoy creando un formulario en android con kotlin y estoy tratando de validar dos radiobuttons y enviar la seleccion del radioButton que seleccione a otra activity para que se muestre en la activity quisiera saber como se puede hacer ya que no me esta dando.

```
btnSiguiente.setOnClickListener {

        if (editTextTextPersonName.text.toString() != "" && editTextTextPersonName2.text.toString() != "" && txtCalendar.text.toString() != "") {
            radioSexMas = 
            val intent: Intent = Intent(this, DatosPersonales::class.java)
            var Nombre:String = editTextTextPersonName.text.toString()
            var Apellido:String = editTextTextPersonName2.text.toString()
            radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener { group, checkedId ->
                if (checkedId==R.id.radioSexMas){
                    var Sexo:String = radioSexMas.text.toString()
                    intent.putExtra("Sexo",Sexo)
                }
                if (checkedId==R.id.radioSexFem){
                    var Sexo:String = radioSexFem.text.toString()
                    intent.putExtra("Sexo",Sexo)
                }
            }


            var fecha:String = txtCalendar.text.toString()
            var Escolari:String = spinner1.selectedItem.toString()
            intent.putExtra("Nombre", Nombre)
            intent.putExtra("Apellido", Apellido)

            intent.putExtra("Fecha",fecha)
            intent.putExtra("Escolaridad", Escolari)
            startActivity(intent)
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "ingrese campos obligatorios", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

O bien usas safe args de navigation component https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-pass-data
o para este caso en la activity de destino deberías recuperar los datos del intent dentro del método oncreate.

```
val sex:String = intent.getStringExtra("Sexo").toString()
val name:String = intent.getStringExtra("Name").toString()
val lastName:String = intent.getStringExtra("Apellido").toString()
```